# Selenium chrome Tabs are closing automatically

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I'm facing very strange issue i.e. I'm calling a function inside a loop which opens Selenium Chrome Tabs. After opening almost 4 Tabs if close the previous ones.
I have checked my code multiple times and could not find any bug or reason if it.

```
def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    proxy = get_random_proxy()
    # print(proxy)
    manifest_json, background_json = get_proxy_variables(proxy[0], proxy[1], proxy[2], proxy[3])
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'
        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_json)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
        "source": """
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
          get: () => undefined
        })
      """
    })
    return driver


def open_nike_url(url, user_name, pwd):
    count = 0
    driver = get_chromedriver(True)
    driver.get(url)
    login_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'join-log-in')))
    time.sleep(5)
    login_btn.click()
    driver = log_in(driver, user_name, pwd)
    time.sleep(5)
    pop_up = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("nike-unite-error-close")
    # print("Outside Loop:", len(pop_up))
    return driver

for i in range(len(accounts_info)):
    open_nike_url(url, accounts_info[i][0], accounts_info[i][1])
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Code is just trying to login to a website for every account.
So after login to some accounts it closes previous Tabs.**

Answer (score 0):

I think that tabs gets closed because the driver finish the task into it. As i understood from your code a new WebDriver is created for every tab you open. That means that when the driver ends its task it closes the tab. I think that this happens because you're making all local context drivers. **Try to add a infinite loop for every driver at the end of their task and see if tabs get closed**.

Comment: I'm just overriding the driver handle. I don't understand the reason of this but I solved the issue by maintaining a list and appending the driver for each tab.